# Rapid click event handling on Android

Tags: android

If you very quickly tap 2 separate buttons, or even the same button, Android will process both click events. This becomes an issue when it can start services twice, or show dialogs twice, or start activities over each other, etc.

The fix for preventing double taps on a single button is pretty straight-forward and the answer is all over StackOverflow. You can simply check whether the button has been clicked using a boolean flag and stop processing any further click events.

My issue is that the user may rapidly press two (or more) different buttons (or list items, or ActionBar items, etc). Handling every combination of "has button x been clicked -> better disable button x, y, z" would be really tedious and error prone.

Does anyone have a decent solution to this?

Comment: How about _one_ boolean flag: `carryOn` - to indicate whether to go on and process input event - or dispose off it. So, basically there will be 2 states - check inside event listener==> if (carryOn) { carryOn = false; ... } You will also need to release the lock when you are done. It does sound quite cumbersome. I'm hoping that someone posts a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you very quickly tap 2 separate buttons, or even the same button, Android will process both click events. This becomes an issue when it can start services twice, or show dialogs twice, or start activities over each other, etc.

A well-written UI is idempotent, often via validation:

- don't start the service if you did that already
- don't show the dialog if the dialog is showing
- don't start another activity if you already did and have not yet been stopped yourself
- don't re-delete an item that is already deleted
- etc.

In some cases, developers don't worry about being fully idempotent because the framework handles it (e.g., given a well-written `onStartCommand()` method, starting a service twice should not be an issue; you cannot delete the same _ID twice). In some cases, developers don't worry about being fully idempotent because the impacts on the user are non-destructive (e.g., starting an activity twice). In some cases, developers don't worry about the problem because the trigger mechanism effectively blocks duplicate effects (e.g., long-press).

And in some cases, we're just lazy. :-)

But the validation should be for the *work*, not the *trigger*. Whether we are starting the service due to a button click, an action item click, a list row click, a shake of the device, an incoming GCM message, or whatever, we need to ensure that the work is handled in an idempotent fashion.

> My issue is that the user may rapidly press two (or more) different buttons (or list items, or ActionBar items, etc).

This is transcending idempotence. It is also fairly unlikely, insofar as users just aren't that fast in moving their finger -- it's the sort of thing that the Test Monkey will run into more than will ordinary humans. And, it's the sort of thing that, AFAIK, few developers worry about.

If you really want to worry about it, then come up with the minimal possible set of "worry". For example, if the user taps two action bar items in succession, one of which marks the currently-viewed detail as a favorite, and the other of which pops up a dialog to allow the user to associate a password with the currently-viewed detail, who cares? Why is this intrinsically invalid?

But beyond that, yes, it's going to be tedious. You'll need to track all the possible "don't do this work in rapid succession" and determine whether or not you have hit a "rapid succession" case in the various callbacks (`onClick()`, `onListItemClick()`, `onOptionsItemSelected()`). A lot of the code can be factored out into some sort of `EventMonitor` that knows your business rules and can report whether you hit a rapid-succession scenario.

Comment: The `View#cancelPendingInputEvents()` api might help with this issue. See [this commit message](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1487466dc2ce14cccf0ff2bd2f824238aaa0044e%5E%21/).

Answer (score 2):

I’ll pitch in my .02, although this might not qualify as a decent solution. It’s simple and doesn’t take into account e.g. enabling of buttons, scheduling or any other sophisticated action. It may remove some boilerplate, for example disabling of buttons, but comes at a price of the ugly `try-finally` syntax:

```
public final class EventLocker {

    private static Object lock;

    public static synchronized boolean lock(final Object object) {
        if (null == object) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("object must not be null"); }
        if (null == lock) {
            lock = object;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static synchronized boolean release(final Object object) {
        if (null != lock && lock.equals(object)) {
            lock = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then, let’s say you wish to set an OnClickListener on a button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (EventLocker.lock(view)) {
            try {
                doSomething();
            } finally {
                EventLocker.release(view);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you consistently use the lock-unlock idiom, you’re guaranteed e.g. Button B will not do anything until Button A releases the lock. On the plus side, it’s easy enough to add custom requirements, if need be.

---

*Answer to the first comment below:*

You’re absolutely right - a bit of sloppiness on my side for not specifically mentioning that in my answer.

Every `onClick()` event, for example, is post to the main thread queue. Funny enough, it brings up a topic I was inevitably trying to avoid; if the button click events are processed sequentially and don’t leave the main thread, then e.g. double tap is not an anomaly but rather two valid actions being processed one after another in a short period of time.

There really is nothing wrong with that - a short period of 150 milliseconds might not make sense, but 10 seconds might be a completely viable option. In cases like these, I believe it’s best to make sure the `onClick` implementations are clever enough to reuse, rebuild or in any other way handle resources at hand.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it has certainly given me some ideas. It looks like this solution won't help though, because all click events are processed on the main thread so Button B wouldn't do anything before Button A completes anyway. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Hi @Bradley, I've edited my answer, as my reply was to long to fit in a comment. :)

Comment: Yes - At the moment handling each onClick individually is one of the approaches I have considered, but I think that approach seems a bit cumbersome. I am hoping for an answer that is a little more centralised, or easy for other developers to implement without having to think too much about all the other interactions.